# Wait until QThread signal´s function is finished (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, wait, qthread

I am using Qthread objects to load dataframes in QTableView widgets (I use personalized abstract model to load even faster) . I use a signal in the QThread to load the data in the widget, because in the QThrear are not allowed the use of widgets. Here the thread:

```
class load_tables(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self,parent=None,index=0,df=None,tabletype=0,extracount=0):
        super(load_tables,self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.df = df
        self.tabletype = tabletype
        self.extracount = extracount

    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...',self.index)
        
        self.any_signal.emit((self.df,self.tabletype,self.extracount))
        
        self.finished.emit(self.index)
```

The 'self.anysignal.emit()' runs a function that needs some time to finish, it loads large data in the widget.

The problem is that when I use '.wait()' to wait the thread finish before advance in the code, the thread finish very fast and the main code keep running, but the function that runs with the QThread signal is still running (I guess).

How can I wait until the function of the signal is finished?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you wait for the thread to complete its execution you're completely losing the utility of the thread. Also note that if the function is CPU bound (no I/O access, just pure computation), threading will do very little, as the python GIL prevents actual concurrency.

Comment: in the example is only one thread but i am running multiple threads, in each one i am loading a widget with a dataframe. The code was I/O bound, i used standard QTableWidget with threads and i got a lot of improve because of threads, so i think with this I am in the good way.

Comment: Then, the problem still remains: if you *wait* for the thread to get those values, you're blocking the execution.

Comment: @AndoEH Why do you need to wait? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If some parts of the gui aren't usable while the data is loading you can temporarily disable them.